# Can we render multiple images in a box in r shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to render multiple images in a single box in R Shiny app. For images i am referring to a location where i have these images. Now when i have only 1 image at the folder the image gets rendered, But as soon as i have more than 1 image at the location it doesn't render anything.

Using below code in server to create a list of images present in that folder

```
output$images <- renderImage({
    
    file <- list.files('~/www', pattern=NULL, all.files=FALSE,full.names=T)
    
    file <- as.data.frame(file)
    
    filename <- normalizePath(file.path(file$file))
    
    filename <- as.list(filename)
    
    list(src = filename) # List gets created till this point but image is not rendered
    
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
```

Comment: You don't know in advance how many images are there? The solution depends on the way you want to display the images. Like a row? A column? A grid?

Comment: Yes i am not aware about the number of images i would want it to be printed in a row.